# Different result for activity and production exchange

Tags: brightway

I get really strange results when running LCA on a self-created activity. The score for the process is something like 1e24 but when I print the scores for its exchanges, they are all around 1 and the production exchange (production amount of 1) has a score of around 8 which is close to a satisfying value for me. Has anyone come through this kind of issue or could explain why I get this ? Thank you very much.

Here is what I get when running the Exchange problem solver : (the 0 exchanges are expected)

```
'_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None) ('E4T', '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu')
Exchange: 1 kg '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)' (kg, GLO, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('E4T', '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of scrap aluminium, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '3c59616fc3bbe826a4b678a7abcbc7f8')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of scrap copper, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', 'f95ce693b0eccbf0bff1efaa6404e948')
Exchange: -1.1624999999999999 kilogram 'treatment of scrap steel, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', 'ae90165b719e1d5f845e5009247a480c')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of scrap tin sheet, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '8d000316c55847f883e812b730d1422e')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste glass, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '6b89808f2ab32b667edec826e026b59d')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste graphical paper, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '2435d4d0acc560df626e1c2a4e0d9d04')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste paperboard, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', 'f9f40ac2f0c47b7c2ccb7decad31a8a3')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste graphical paper, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '2435d4d0acc560df626e1c2a4e0d9d04')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste graphical paper, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '2435d4d0acc560df626e1c2a4e0d9d04')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste paint, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '697c8738655c959c8b7c1af8ff16ffb3')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste plastic, mixture, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '94705189b5c5228845ef704da079eba8')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste polyethylene, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '934b77606b3e7f9f42cfd7e009641168')
Exchange: -0.19375 kilogram 'treatment of waste polypropylene, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '6d47bd47868d34b291118e51ac922540')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste polystyrene, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '0bc94608ea455a6da5c34aa09d5bd5f6')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste polyurethane, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', 'db69868236255cb83d79da02d2bfae5d')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste polyvinylchloride, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '860b4dba14c8ee9c46756957477235de')
Exchange: -3.7199999999999998 kilogram 'treatment of waste rubber, unspecified, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '7d6e94bc691fd65ad47636e33ca19fb7')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste textile, soiled, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', 'b2988f028678bae3feb3c091b4020ecd')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of waste wood, untreated, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '4cf588e35ba44325bc1336bb60d02732')
Exchange: -0.0 kilogram 'treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration' (kilogram, FR, None) to '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu' (kg, GLO, None)>
     ('ecoinvent 3.6', '079723cdbfd0fa7d30e65f48af27e273')
```

And when running the following code :

```
method = [m for m in bw.methods if 'IPCC 2013' in str(m) and 'GWP 100a' in str(m) and not 'no LT' in str(m)][0]
score = y.LCA_calc_score(method,my_activity,1)
print(score)

for exc in my_activity.exchanges() :
    score = y.LCA_calc_score(method,exc.input,exc['amount'])
    print(score,exc.input,exc['type'])
```

I get :

```
-1.0311343621766253e+24
-0.5593820228176581 '_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U (sans procédés obsolètes)' (kg, GLO, None) production
0.0 'treatment of scrap aluminium, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of scrap copper, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) technosphere
0.012501960171068006 'treatment of scrap steel, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of scrap tin sheet, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste glass, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste graphical paper, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste paperboard, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste graphical paper, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste graphical paper, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste paint, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste plastic, mixture, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste polyethylene, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.49068734863333907 'treatment of waste polypropylene, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste polystyrene, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste polyurethane, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste polyvinylchloride, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
11.735510474450567 'treatment of waste rubber, unspecified, municipal incineration' (kilogram, RoW, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste textile, soiled, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of waste wood, untreated, municipal incineration' (kilogram, CH, None) technosphere
0.0 'treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration' (kilogram, FR, None) technosphere
```

(The LCA_cal_score function is the following :)

```
def LCA_calc_score(self, method, process, amount):
        """
        Calculates the LCA score for given method and functional unit.
        
        : param : method = tuple, LCA method from Brightway
        : param : process = tuple, activity corresponding to the functional unit
        : param : amount = float, amount of the activity corresponding to the functional unit
        
        : return : lca.score = float, LCA score from the Brightway calculation
        
        """
        
        #Definition of the functional unit
        functional_unit = {process:amount}
        
        #Definition of the LCA
        lca = bw.LCA(functional_unit,method)
        #Use of the Brightway functions for the inventory and the impact assessment
        lca.lci()
        lca.lcia()
        
        return lca.score
```

Comment: Can you add the result of this code to help clarify the question: https://gist.github.com/cmutel/a4b55ad04eccc3bced5cf23c071265da

Comment: I added the result and other codes to help clarify the question. Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: There is not need to follow broken SimaPro naming conventions when making your own activities. For example, `_Municipal solid waste (waste scenario) {FR}| treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration | Cut-off, U`. Don't do this! The name is in the `name` field, the reference product in its own field, etc.

Comment: I know, it is just that I imported the activities as they were written in Simapro and this one was written this way by my colleagues but it is an exception, the others are written the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity `(sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu` doesn't have a reasonable production exchange. Instead, there is an exchange labelled `production`, but it is *from* `(sans procédés obsolètes)` to `(sans procédés obsolètes)__pneu`. Production exchanges are from and to the same activity.

Comment: Ok thank you, I now see the mistake, I was duplicating another activity's production exchange instead of creating a new one. I changed this and the results are fine now. Thank you very much.